# Choosing row based on json value sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column which saves json values as text. I want to select columns in query based on a certain value contained in the text field.

To be clear, I have a column `server_response` which saves data as follows:

> {
>    "Success": true,
>    "PasswordNotExpired": true,
>    "Exists": true,
>    "Status": "A",
>    "Err": null,
>    "Statuscode": 200,
>    "Message": "Login Denied"
>   }

How can i choose columns based on if the message was/or contained Login Denied in the where clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick, at least this is what i understood you want:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE server_response LIKE '%Login Denied%'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE server_response->>Message LIKE '%Login Denied%'
```

Note: <sup>[source](http://stormatics.com/howto-use-json-functionality-in-postgresql/)</sup>

> The `->` operator returns a JSON object.
>   The `->>` operator returns TEXT.